# Unable To Retrieve Location GeoFire Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm trying to retrieve a **GeoFire** location saved on Firebase but it's returning null. Tried saving the location lat & lng with a global & local double variable but still the same.

> Common.worker_tracking_table = "WorkerTracking"
>
> Common.workerType = "Carpenters"

Already verified that these values are not null.

```
final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Common.worker_tracking_table).child(Common.workerType);
        final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(dbRef);

        geoFire.getLocation(Common.workerId, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                if(location != null) {
                    Common.updatedLat = location.latitude;
                    Common.updatedLng = location.longitude;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

Here's the database:

[image]

Comment: Please log those values which you are getting in your anonymous callback i.e in String

Comment: The only value I need from the callback is the location, which is returning null that’s why I get an error when I try to log it, error is java lang null

Comment: in above case what is Common.workerId ?, it must be M57KTDiA...........

Comment: Common.workerId is `M57K..`, printed it out as well to verify it is really`M57K..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird and I can't even explain how in the world it's possible but I was able to retrieve the location by removing the `if` statement leaving it like this:

```
final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Common.worker_tracking_table).child(Common.workerType);
    final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(dbRef);

    geoFire.getLocation(Common.workerId, new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            Common.updatedLat = location.latitude;
            Common.updatedLng = location.longitude;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```